# Minecraft sun, how?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If the regular Minecraft world is infinite, how does the sun revolve around it? Please elaborate as much as you can if you wish to answer such a crazy and unimaginable question~!

Comment: Please be more specific to the question you are asking please.

Comment: First of all, the world isn't infinite. The maximum world size is just 30 million by 30 million blocks (or meters). Secondly, Minecraft is a **game**, it doesn't follow our world's physics. I mean, how does one individual carry several stacks of gold in one's inventory? Finally, the sun is a paid actor.

Answer (score 3):

From a lore perspective: this is a world of spells, monsters, alternate dimensions and dragons. You could say that the sun is a "protective spell" that stops the bad monsters from coming.

However, that's purely speculation. There is actually no "lore" in this game, other than the "End Credits", after you defeat the Ender Dragon and jump back through the portal.

---

Realistically however; this is just a video game. What they are referring to when they talk about the world being "infinite" is that the game is programmed to generate the world by what is called using an [infinite loop](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/infinite-loop-endless-loop).

> An infinite loop (sometimes called an endless loop ) is a piece of coding that lacks a functional exit so that it repeats indefinitely. In computer programming, a loop is a sequence of instruction s that is continually repeated until a certain condition is reached. […] If the presence of the specified condition cannot be ascertained, the next instruction in the sequence tells the program to return to the first instruction and repeat the sequence, which typically goes on until the program terminates automatically after a certain duration of time, or the operating system terminates the program with an error.

In Minecraft, this is what happens when it generates the world, but to stop the program from crashing (or blowing up your computer), is to [limit this to a maximum size of the map](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Overworld#Limitations).

> While the world is virtually infinite, the number of blocks a player may physically reach is limited. Where the limits are depends on the edition of the game and the world type being played.

And ultimately, the actual "night" and "day" cycles are simply a timed mechanic that allow the game to be more interesting, and don't actually follow any laws of physics.